# How to add new occ endpoints paramater to get url?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I am referencing defaultOccProductConfig and want to add new endpoint to get url dynamicly.

For example;

```
productReviews: 'products/${productCode}/reviews', // this is existing endpoint
productManipulation: 'products/${productCode}/manipulation' // this is what i want to add
```

I am getting an error when add this endpoint after import module. How can i override my new endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your nodule (i.e. app module) please provide your custom config chunk by importing `ConfigModule.withConfig()`. For example:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    /* ... */
    ConfigModule.withConfig({
      backend: {
        occ: {
          endpoints: {
            productManipulation: 'products/${productCode}/manipulation' // this is what i want to add
          }
        }
      }
    })
    /* ... */
  ]
})
export class AppModule {};
```

For more, see docs:

- https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/connecting-to-other-systems/#configuring-endpoints
- https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/global-configuration-in-spartacus/#configmodulewithconfig

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked for me, I was trying to add this in B2cStorefrontModule.withConfig so it returns me an error.